# How to get case insensitive text results using OCR

Tags: matlab, ocr

I want this kind of result:

```
'THis IS aN EXAmpLE'
```

To be like this:

```
'THIS IS AN EXAMPLE'
```

or this:

```
'this is an example'
```

Is there any parameter I can send to `ocr` to achieve this?

```
txt = ocr(img,my_region,'Language','MyLanguage')`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply apply [`upper`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/upper.html) or [`lower`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lower.html) to the result from `ocr` to get the uppercase and lowercase versions, respectively.

```
txt = ocr(img, my_region, 'Language', 'MyLanguage');

uppercase = upper(txt.Text);
lowercase = lower(txt.Text);
```